# How can I design a 'checkbox experience' for a message/text based bot?

Tags: checkboxes, onboarding, chatbots, checklist

I'm looking to design decent solution for reflecting 'checkbox functionality' in Slack.

I'm working on a bot and during the onboarding process I need the user to set some preferences while talking to the bot. One of the preferences requires them to indicate which options from a list (5-10 items) they are interested in. In a web/mobile UI I would just use a checklist for this but I need to figure out an affective way to do the some thing via the messaging UI.

Is there an existing solution or pattern I can follow?

Answer (score 2):

I'd think the most human-like method would work best. Ask them the settings one by one, with a short preface.

```
We will now start with configuration. Please answer yes or no.

Make use of cauliflower defenestration?
```

> yes

```
Deconfibulate the triblomatics?
```

> no

```
Alphabetically Sort typographies?
```

> YESS

Remember to sanitize and check for variations of user inputs!

Comment: I agree with PixelSnader. Also, It makes sense to ask a "question" and expect an "answer" rather than having to click a check box. Let the user type his "answer" than selecting from a list

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, numbered list would work best as a checkbox replacement in conversational bots.

Consider an example, you want from your user to place an order of a combo containing maximum 3 items from the available menu options.

> **BOT**
>
> Hi there!
>
> Here is the list of available options below, you can
>   select a combo of maximum 3 items. Give your choice in numbers, for
>   example write: **1, 4, 8** to order **Burger + Pizza + Orange Juice**.
>
> List:
>
> 1. Burger
> 2. Pasta
> 3. Noodles
> 4. Pizza
> 5. Chocolate Milkshake
> 6. Strawberry Milkshake
> 7. Sweet Lime Juice
> 8. Orange Juice

```
User: 1,4,8
```

> Please review your order, you’ve made a choice of:
>
> *Burger, Pizza and Orange Juice*
>
> (type **‘Yes’** to **confirm** or **‘No’** to **re-select** your choices)

```
User: yes
```

> **BOT**
>
> Bingo! Order saved.

Comment: and what if the user made a mistake and wants to remove 4 from 1 4 8

Comment: @PirateApp ‘No’ to re-select your choices